# setCouponCode not working in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, coupon

> SalesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore

This observer will dispatch when the shipment is selected. After that, I need to apply a coupon code.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{    

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

    $couponCode = "FIRSTORDER";
    $quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)
                              ->collectTotals()
                              ->save(); 
}
```

I created a coupon code **FIRSTORDER**. But I try to execute the function I am getting the following error.

> "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

How to solve this issue?. How can I apply the coupon code? please share your valuable feedback

Comment: Try this code:   $quote = $observer->getQuote();
  $couponCode = "FIRSTORDER";
  $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()
   ->save();

"OR"

$quote = $observer->getQuote();
$couponCode = "FIRSTORDER";
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals();

Comment: Which observer you have tried?

Comment: @Abdul I tried but it still getting the same error. totaly stcuk

Comment: i have tried sales_quote_collect_totals_before this observer @SohelRana. But I remove the setcupon everything clear. there is no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $couponCode = "FIRSTORDER";
        $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)
            ->save();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Tested with M2.2 working fine.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214894/how-to-add-condition-in-cart-price-rule please check my new question

Comment: The cart summary is not refreshing while applying this coupon using this method in case of cache enabled in admin. Do you have any idea about this?