# How to add condition in cart price rule?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, promotions

> Function to generate cart price rule

```
public function generateCoupon($value='')
{
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$coupon['name']     =   'PROMO1';
$coupon['desc']     =   'Promotion one';
$coupon['start']    =   date('Y-m-01');
$coupon['end']      =   date('Y-m-t');
$coupon['max_redemptions']  =   1;
$coupon['discount_type']    =   'by_percent';
$coupon['discount_amount']  =   30;
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions']      =   1;
$coupon['code']             =   "PROMOPROMO2";
$coupon['store_labels']     =   '3k-4.9k 30% discount'; //this code will normally be autogenetated but i am hard coding for testing purposes

$shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
$shoppingCartPrice = $shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
        ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
        ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
        ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
        ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('1',))
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
        ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
        ->setDiscountQty(1)
        ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
        ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
        ->setStoreLabels(array('40% Discount For First Order','40% Discount For First Order'))
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
        ->setCouponType(2)
        ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
        $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();}
```

The above function create coupon code successfully. But there is a condition, I have to add a condition that order amount is greater than 5000. Then only coupon is accessible. How can i add this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
 */
protected $ruleFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\AddressFactory
 */
protected $addressFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\AddressFactory $addressFactory
) {
    $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
    $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
}
```

And now

```
public function addSalesRule()
{
    $sku = '24-WG085';
    $shoppingCartPriceRule = $this->ruleFactory->create();

    $shoppingCartPriceRule->setName('Add a second for $1 - ' . $sku)
        ->setDescription('Buy one item at regular price, and receive a second item for just $1.00 more!')
        ->setFromDate('2000-01-01')
        ->setToDate(NULL)
        ->setUsesPerCustomer('0')
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
        ->setIsActive('1')
        ->setStopRulesProcessing('0')
        ->setIsAdvanced('1')
        ->setProductIds(NULL)
        ->setSortOrder('1')
        ->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
        ->setDiscountAmount(30)
        ->setDiscountQty(NULL)
        ->setDiscountStep('0')
        ->setApplyToShipping('0')
        ->setTimesUsed('0')
        ->setIsRss('0')
        ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
        ->setCouponType('1')
        ->setCouponCode(NULL)
        ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);

    // Add Subtotal Condition
    $skuCond = $this->addressFactory->create()
        ->setType('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address')
        ->setAttribute('base_subtotal')
        ->setOperator('>=')
        ->setValue(5000);
    $shoppingCartPriceRule->getConditions()->addCondition($skuCond);
    $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
}
```

Comment: is it possible to add a customer session to condition, Because I have two type cusotmer. The coupon is eligible for one type of users.

Comment: Can you please answer this question [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223389/access-token-in-integration-gives-unauthorized-access-error)

Comment: @Sohel, can you please check this code, I am trying to same condition applying on this. but not working.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357162/magento-2-4-0-how-to-i-can-apply-cart-price-rule-condition-in-this-coupon-code